# What are the advantages and disadvantages of storing normalized data in SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, database-normalization, entity-relationship

I have a database that is designed to store horse racing times. Currently, I have a `Race` table and a `RaceTimes` table. Each has 5 fractional times and five split times. The `RaceTime` table also includes a `Race` foreign key.

For example:

`RaceTime` table:

```
    RaceTime_id (primary key)
    Race_id  (foreign key)
    TimeValue  (time stored in 100th of seconds)
    PointOfTime (i.e. 1/4 mile, 1/2 mile, etc.)
    Which (where which is an integer between 1 and 5)
```

Given that there are five times and five splits for each race, this approach yields 10 `RaceTime` records for each race.  Alternatively, I could create a database structure that includes: Fraction1, Fraction2....Fraction5 and Split1, Split2...Split5. Under this approach there would be a 1 for 1 match between the `Race` record and the `RaceTime` record and the `RaceTime` table would have far fewer rows.

My reading and research lead me to believe the first approach is preferable. I believe this data is more normalized. I guess I have some pause because of the difference in the table size, but perhaps its just a trade-off between a long or wide table.

That said, I was hoping to get input from those more well versed in these matters, I'm just an accountant who likes playing the horses. Thanks for your input.

Comment: "I'm just an accountant who likes playing the horses" and is implementing a SQL table to help? Sir/ma'am, I like the cut of your jib.

Answer (score 3):

You are right - first approach is better. Disadvantages of second approach:

1. Difficulties with adding new fraction or split (sometime rules are changed, or exotic races appears)
2. Problems when you need to select data by fraction or split. You need to create indexes on 5 fraction and 5 split columns. This will decrease performance a lot.
3. Code that select data from such table should explicitly process this additional columns. Instead of using loops you need to hardcode fields Fraction1, ..., Fraction5 and Split1, ..., Split5. And due to duplicated pieces of code some mistakes can occur.

Second approach however has a bit better performance but modern applications use cache to "remember" denormalized data. So this advantage is insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

It'll depend heavily on the sort of queries you're performing on the table. If you normalize your table as your code sample indicates, you'll end up having to do a `JOIN` and some extra processing to retrieve data for a given race. This shouldn't be too slow if your database is well-indexed, but it is a bit of extra work.

However, if you're confident there will be five, no more and no less, splits/fractions for any given race, denormalizing it (the `Split1...Split5` way) will get you slightly better performance, but will be a giant pain if you ever have to (say) add a sixth split.

Your call; only you can know what's best for your app.

Comment: @ternus In my example there are always 5 fractions and splits, but in practice there can be 3 or 4 fractions or splits.  Is the performance boost offered by the second alternative attributable to the number of records.

Comment: No, just that you don't have to do a SQL `JOIN` to retrieve all the splits/fractions. If you know there will **always** be less than 5, you can create the fields for 5 and leave some of them as null. But if there's **any doubt at all** just normalize the data, lest the Ghost of Technical Debt Future visit you in the middle of the night.

Comment: See [SQL Server Infernals - Part 1 - Undernormalizers](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/06/17/sql-server-infernals-row-1-undernormalizers/) and check out the "Clues you’re doing it wrong" - especially the point "Columns with a numeric suffix (e.g. Zone1, Zone2, Zone3...)". Seriously: **don't do it!** No matter what you think - it ***WILL*** come back to haunt you (or your successor) some day. So just don't do it (and most definitely **don't recommend it** to others!) - properly normalize your data!

Comment: @marc_s If it's a personal project, I doubt it matters to that extent, and in my experience, the "everything must be normalized to the nth degree" dogma can lead to equally unmaintainable apps. Overnormalization can lead to impossible-to-understand schemas, which can be just as bad.